# Failed to get frame-benchmarking as a dependency of package

Tags: build, cargo

After pulling from the tutorials/solutions/add-a-pallet, The build process with cargo gives an error.

cargo build --release
See error
Expected vs. Actual Behavior
The build process is not complete.

Environment
Operating system: Linux/Ubuntu
Brach: tutorials/solutions/add-a-pallet
Rust version : 1.24.3
Logs, Errors or Screenshots

error: failed to get frame-benchmarking as a dependency of package node-template v4.0.0-dev (/home/ubuntu/source/repos/substrate-node-template/node)

Caused by:
failed to load source for dependency frame-benchmarking

Caused by:
Unable to update https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=devhub/latest#352c46a6

Caused by:
object not found - no match for id (352c46a648a5f2d4526e790a184daa4a1ffdb3bf); class=Odb (9); code=NotFound (-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that you have an inconsistency somewhere in one of your cargo manifests (`Cargo.toml` files).

It is requesting the `Benchmarking pallet`, but it is not included. Would would need to give much more detail about what you are doing though.

Comment: I updated the cargo files with polkadot-v0.9.12 branch. and run again cargo build --release.The error occurs again.

Comment: You can get branch  origin/tutorials/solutions/add-a-pallet and build the project And see what happens.